# Stacking multiple bitmaps set transparency to black

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I've been trying to figure it out but can't find the right way to do this.
I render a swc file to get a Bitmap, it's a simple circle. It works fine, but when I stack multiple instances of this Bitmap (~50 instances), I can see transparency being replaced by solid black. It's on a particle system, so I tried it with a simple loop stacking multiple transparent images, and I have the exact same issue. Is there any workaround?
Thanks!

[image: Transparent bitmapdata becomes black]

Comment: Long long ago (like really long ago, back in 2002-2003) I've had the similar issue in Flash 6 (http://delimiter.ru/games/25-lines/057-25-lines.html). I experimented on it a bit and found out that setting the global quality to "LOW" somehow resolves the problem. Not sure if that would help but still.

Comment: Most likely your bitmap that you use to draw these particles on (the one that you then use to draw each particle) is initialized with 0x0 color. You might try switching it to 0x00808080 and check if these corners would turn gray. If yes, you can change that color to whatever green you use as a background with zero alpha to blend these corners. As I get it, the effect is somehow related to 24+ transparent bitmaps layered with Flash engine, and is pretty much incurable except for changing the amount of particles drawn at a certain place.

Comment: If still not solved then also try using `copyPixels` (_see:_ [**BitmapData** manual](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#copyPixels())). If you need some effects like a fading alpha, then do that to the container MC or Sprite parent of the Bitmap object.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but I didn't get it working in the end. I just stacked less images. I guess copyPixels should work, but it's a hell of a revamp for that effect.